# What HTML Form Action to use when no data is actually being sent?

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I am working on learning JQuery and creating a simple HTML / JS calculator. I used a standard HTML form to allow the user to enter the data they want calculated and when the user clicks submit my JS / JQuery calculates and spits out the answer.

My question is what would be the semantically correct way to deal with the HTML form action being that Im not actually posting any data? I dont want to leave it default because when I click my  to trigger an event it changes the URL and I dont want to use POST because Im not posting anything. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to have a form at all?  Since you're using JS, you shouldn't need to do anything server-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would replace the submit button with a normal button, and prevent the form being "submitted" at all. then use javascript to do the calculations on button click. This way the form never gets submitted, and you don't need a method or action at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do a request at all, you probably just want to do a `GET`...check the [list of HTTP request methods here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_methods) to see if another one would better fit your needs.

If you are doing everything with javascript, though, you shouldn't be submitting anything at all.  Try changing the submit button into a link (or just a regular button) and bind your calculator logic to its `click` event.

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify any action(Default is GET). Use an html button which would call the js function on the click event. That would do the work on client side

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to put `input` elements inside a `form`. Since you don't intend to submit the form, I would just omit it entirely.